# Build (vectorizer.idf_) function of Sklearn with from Scratch

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, tfidfvectorizer

I am implementing sklearn's (vectorizer.idf_) function from scratch and compare the result. So for a given corpus for say,

SKLEARN IMPLEMENTATION:-

```
corpus = [
     'this is the first document',
     'this document is the second document',
     'and this is the third one',
     'is this the first document',
]

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
vectorizer.fit(corpus)
skl_output = vectorizer.transform(corpus)

print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())

OUTPUT:- ['and', 'document', 'first', 'is', 'one', 'second', 'the', 'third', 'this']

print(vectorizer.idf_)

OUTPUT:- [1.91629073 1.22314355 1.51082562 1.         1.91629073 1.91629073
 1.         1.91629073 1.        ]
```

My Custom Code is as follows where i have a fit() method which converts the corpus into a dictionary and a functino called idf() where it will count a particular word is occuring how many times in a given corpus and a transform() function where i am calculating the idf values.

```
corpus = [
     'this is the first document',
     'this document is the second document',
     'and this is the third one',
     'is this the first document',
]

def fit(dataset):
    storage_set = set()
    if isinstance(dataset,list):
        for document in dataset:
            for word in document.split(" "):
                storage_set.add(word)
        storage_set = sorted(list(storage_set))
        vocab = {j:i for i,j in enumerate(storage_set)}
        #Idf_values_of_all_unique_words=IDF(dataset,storage_set)
        
    #print(list(storage_set))
    return vocab

vocab =  fit(corpus)
print(vocab)

OUTPUT:- {'and': 0, 'document': 1, 'first': 2, 'is': 3, 'one': 4, 'second': 5, 'the': 6, 'third': 7, 'this': 8}

def idf(dataset,word):
    count=0
    for row in dataset:
        if word in row:
            count+=1            
    return count

def transform(dataset,vocab):
    row = []
    col = []
    values = []
    idf_value=[]
    
    for ibx,document in enumerate(dataset):
        word_freq = dict(Counter(document.split()))
        for word, freq in word_freq.items():
            col_index = vocab.get(word,-1)
            if col_index != -1:
                if len(word)<2:
                    continue
                col.append(col_index)
                row.append(ibx)
                
                term_freq = freq/(len(document)) # the number of times a word occured in a document
                idf_ = 1+math.log((1+len(dataset))/(1+idf(dataset,word)))
                
                
                values.append((term_freq) * (idf_))
                
                idf_value.append(idf_)
    print(idf_value)

OUTPUT:- [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.5108256237659907, 1.2231435513142097, 1.0, 1.2231435513142097, 1.0, 1.0, 1.916290731874155, 1.916290731874155, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.916290731874155, 1.916290731874155, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.5108256237659907, 1.2231435513142097]
```

so if i compare the sklearn output for idf score it is an array of 9 values as there are 9 different words in the corpus but i am getting an array of size 22. Can someone help me to understand where i'm doing it wrong.

Comment: use `print()` to see values in variables and which lines of code are executed - and compare it with calculations on paper.

Comment: you have nested `for`-loops - first runs 4 times (number of documents) , inner runs 9 times (number of words) so it may produce even 36 elements. It can means you calculate it in wrong way. Probably you keep every value separatelly - for every document separated value. But for every word you should cumulate values from all documents. maybe you shoudl keep result as `values[word] = [result1, result2]` and later use all of them to calculate `(term_freq) * (idf_)`

Answer (score 0):

To calculate `idf_` it needs only one loop.

```
def transform(dataset, vocab):
    idf_value = []

    dataset_len = len(dataset)

    for word in vocab:
        idf_ = 1 + math.log( (1 + dataset_len) / (1 + idf(dataset, word)) )
        idf_value.append(idf_)
                
    print(idf_value)
```

Because you run it in other loop so `append()` is adding the same value many times.

So you could first calculate alll `idf_` to add them to list.

Or you should keep `idf_` as dictionary `word: idf_` and then adding again the same `idf_` doesn't make problem.

---

This code gives me the same results as `vectorizer.idf_`

It gives almost the same result as `skl_output` (I have to multiply by 10) but few values are different - and I don't know why.

```
def transform(dataset, vocab):
    values = []
    idf_value=[]

    dataset_len = len(dataset)

    for word in vocab:
        idf_ = 1 + math.log( (1 + dataset_len) / (1 + idf(dataset, word)) )
        idf_value.append(idf_)

    print(idf_value)
        
    for doc_idx, document in enumerate(dataset):
        document_len = len(document)
        word_freq = dict(Counter(document.split()))

        for word, freq in word_freq.items():
            word_idx = vocab[word]
            
            term_freq = freq/document_len
            idf_ = 1 + math.log( (1 + dataset_len) / (1 + idf(dataset, word)) )
            
            values.append( ((doc_idx, word_idx), term_freq * idf_ * 10))
            
    for item in values:
        print(item)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Better use `split(' ')` when you check

```
    if word in row.split(' '):
```

because `"is" in "this"` gives `True` but you need `False`
and `"is" in ["this"]` gives correctly `False`